# Can't execute script from within rc.local

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Within rc.local I have

```
sudo -H -u myUser -s -- "cd /home/myUser/parlar && /usr/local/bin/meteor &"
```

I want to test it but when I execute that with

```
myUser:~$ sudo service rc.local start
/bin/bash: cd /home/myUser/parlar && /usr/local/bin/meteor &: No such file or directory
```

If I execute the command

```
cd /home/myUser/parlar && /usr/local/bin/meteor &
```

it works

How can I execute rc.local so that it changes into the relevant directory, and runs the command as the requested user?

Comment: Try: `sudo -H -u myUser -s -- bash -c "cd /home/myUser/parlar && /usr/local/bin/meteor &"`

Comment: @anishsane thanks that worked. Please put that as a response so I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever arguments you give to sudo after `--` are considered as command & its arguments.

There is no command/executable named "cd /home/myUser/parlar && /usr/local/bin/meteor". You can however, start bash & run the command within that bash shell.

e.g.

```
sudo -H -u myUser -s -- bash -c "cd /home/myUser/parlar && /usr/local/bin/meteor &"
```

Since the first command is `cd`, this alternate approach may also work:

```
sudo -H -u myUser -s -i PWD=/home/myUser/parlar -- /usr/local/bin/meteor
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the log of rc.local itself, it's better to run these commands:

```
**systemctl restart rc-local.service**

**systemctl status rc-local.service**
```

May be it can be help full for better trouble shooting